# How to use border-spacing in fullcalendar

Tags: css, width, fullcalendar, cellspacing

I'm trying to style the fullcalendar jquery plugin, and have it mostly set, with one problem. I want to have spacing between the cells (ie. so can see background behind table), which I can do by overriding the css border-spacing property, however when I do that, the width calculations for fullcalendar get thrown off, and my far right column ('Saturday' in month view) gets shrunk. Is there any way to tell fullcalendar that I'm using spacing, or some other way to have that calculated through?
Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 1):

can you add this to the issue tracker?
http://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/list

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue that you are facing.  As opposed to digging through the .js i just 'fixed' this with css by adding width to the fc-sat column with addclass, matching the width of the other columns of the desired #calendar width.

```
$(function () {
    $('.fc-sat').addClass('adjustit');
});
```

With these classes in my css

```
<style>
#calendar{width:780px;}
.adjustit{width:103px !important;}
</style>
```

Hope this helps.